# Python: Generating a big uniform permutation cheaply

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

I'm not sure whether this is possible even theoretically; but if it is, I'd like to know how to do it in Python.

I want to generate a big, random permutation cheaply. For example, say that I want a permutation on `range(10**9)`. I want the permutation to be uniform (i.e. I want the numbers to be all over the place without  any seeming structure.) I want to have a function available to get the nth item in the permutation for each `n`, and I want to have another function available to get the index of every number in the permutation.

And the big, final condition is this: I want to do all of that without having to store all the items of the permutation. (Which can be a huge amount of space.) I want each item to be accessible, but I don't want to store all the items, like `range` in Python 3.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd like to hear a bit more about the application. What is it exactly that's preventing you from just using random integers in a range?

Comment: I don't see much hope for for doing this in terms of permutations. Simply storing *which* of the 10**9! permutations you've selected takes more than 10 GiB, via the `ln n!` approximation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Versions_suitable_for_calculators -- this, coupled with the fact that no feasible PRNG has a period long enough to generate an appreciable fraction of those permutations, means you'll have to settle for a tiny, regular subset of the permutations. On the other hand, if you only want some (unique?) numbers from `range(10**9)`...

Comment: Linear feedback shift registers can have a very big period, and they generate each number once, in a seemingly random order.

Comment: Now that I think about it, wouldn't a block cipher like AES fit this bill exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a block cipher, like AES, provides exactly this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this happening and partially fulfilling your requirements is if the permutation is not random but looks random, and is really a series from which you can generate a_n if you know a_n-1.

Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register
What you want is a maximum length LSFR. It will generate all numbers for 0 to 2**n-1 once, in a seemingly random order. For different n you need to use a different function.

I think you can't have functions getIdxOf(val) and getValOf(Idx) however, unless you just go through the generating functions one by one.